# Showing result on Tabhost in android/eclipse

Tags: android, android-tabhost

[image]

The above emulator image is just getting the input from the user and showing the answer in the edittext of the same page.But i need to show that answer on the Tabhost ( which wants to be on the next page ) like the below image..

[image]

How to achieve this concept..?

Comment: [Refer this one...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) Use Shared preferences to store values, then you can access it in your Tabhost.

Comment: Can you please send me any example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: just call your tab activity class !!

Comment: KMI If i did like so what you said it just showing the answer on the separate screen...

Comment: hey call the activity which extends tab activity

Comment: KMI its again showing the same things what i said early,can you plz give me solution to this. will i send u my code

Comment: KMI how can i chat with you to discuss about android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can call the same tab when u calling the activity
just put id to your current tab and call the tab when u call a activity 
--put it in TabActivity

```
public void switchTab(int tab) {
tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
}
```

in the activity call TabActivity

```
TabsActivity ParentActivity;
ParentActivity = (TabsActivity) activity.getParent();
ParentActivity.switchTab(0);// 0 is a current tab id and u can used what ever tab id u want to shift
```

i hop this may help u

Comment: user179777 can you send me some samples for the above code what you have given?